# How to extract and save words before & after a character along with the original string in python

Tags: python, string

Here is a string I need to extract from:

```
Tom and Jerry, Batman and Joker, Homer and Marge
```

The list goes on...and here is the end result I'm hoping to get as output (saved as CSV or something):

```
|Tom|
|Jerry|
|Tom and Jerry|
|Batman|
|Joker|
|Batman and Joker|
|Homer|
|Marge|
|Homer and Marge|
```

I know I can do `.split(",")` to get to `Tom and Jerry` and `.split("and")`to further separate to Tom, Jerry. 
However, how can I keep all three records?

Thanks

Comment: hi, you could perhaps use two separate regexes, or split each comma-separated values and `.extend` the output list.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` returns `list instance` and `list instance` doesn't have a split function. Each different variable is required to take advantage of the execution results of an individual function.

```
text = "Tom and Jerry, Batman and Joker, Homer and Marge"
result = list()
for text_and in text.split(', '):
    if ' and ' in text_and:  # If 'and' doesn't exist in some of input data,
        for text_name in text_and.split(' and '):
            print(f"|{text_name}|")
            result.append(text_name)
    print(f"|{text_and}|")
    result.append(text_and)
```

```
|Tom|
|Jerry|
|Tom and Jerry|
|Batman|
|Joker|
|Batman and Joker|
|Homer|
|Marge|
|Homer and Marge|
```

Here is one-line code using `itertools.chain` function.

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain(*[[*text_and.split(' and '), text_and] if ' and ' in text_and else [text_and] for text_and in text.split(', ')]))
```

```
# result
['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Tom and Jerry', 'Batman', 'Joker', 'Batman and Joker', 'Homer', 'Marge', 'Homer and Marge']
```

Comment: Not sure it matters for the OP, but this will duplicate strings between commas that don't have `and` in them such as `text = "Tom and Jerry, Bart Simpson"`.

Comment: Right. Code only works in the form of input data shown in the question. `"Bart Simpson"` will be transformed to `["Bart Simpson", "Bart Simpson"]`. Thank you for good advice!

Comment: I updated to prevent duplicate